# is there a maximum number of records for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am looking to use MongoDB to store a huge amount of records : between 12 and 15 billions. Is it possible to store this number of documents in mongoDB ?
I saw on the net, that there are limits for : document size, index size, number of elements in collection. 
But is there a limit in terms of number of records ?

Comment: Nope. Read up on [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) to understand how MongoDB can support very large data sets.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit on the number of documents in one collection. However, you are probobly will run into issues with disk, ram, and lookup/update performance. If your data has some kind of logical grouping, I would suggest splinting it between multiple collections, or even instances (on different servers of course).